# Find posts on Meta Stack Overflow by members of a certain community

Tags: feature-request, search, community

The communities of different Stack Exchange sites may differ in what they care for and how they deal with things and such discussions are what each site's meta site is for. However, some questions are relevant for the whole Stack Exchange network and that is what Meta Stack Overflow (MSO) is for. So when a member of a community wants to deal with a question that needs to be dealt with globally rather than locally they make a post on MSO. Such activity might be something that communities want to be able to track. That is, every Stack Exchange community might have an interest in following what their community members is up to on MSO.

Even if people can post bugs, feature requests and other general issues on their local meta there is a bias to deal with more general issues on MSO (as is reflected by https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Also there might be issues MSO that are more relevant to some communities than others, e.g. sites with graphics heavy posts might be more interested in image inclusion and noisy site may be more interested in filtering and moderation tools. It is unfortunate if some issue that is relevant for some community is being discussed on meta without part of the said community being aware.

In implementing ways to follow what certain communities is up to on MSO there will be a tighter integration of different sites' metas and MSO which properly reflects the structure of the network. In short, it will bring the relevant discussions on MSO closer to the respective communities. As of now there is no efficient way to find posts on MSO by users of some particular community, that is, by users that are also users of some particular other Stack Exchange site. Here are some rough ideas of what kind of features I am requesting:

- Add a search or filter option that brings out posts where a certain community is active. Say that I use the filter option to filter out posts in which users from the Super User community is active. The filter would then show activity (questions, answers, comments, etc.) by MSO users who also has an active Super User account.
- Add a link from metas to relevant posts on MSO. This link would lead to a list on MSO filtered by some variant of the above filter, such as active posts where users of the meta in question have been active.

It could be argued that rather Stack Exchange employees should monitor and support migration of relevant posts to MSO. This is a good thing but adding my suggestion would give more power to the communities in tracking relevant issues. Primarily metas should be community driven, not driven by Stack Exchange employees.

It could also be argued that the suggested features would amount to stalking. This is not so. It would not add to the ability to track users, because it is already possible to view user's profiles and see their activity on a certain sites as well as other sites on the network. In analogy to politics, my suggestion only amounts to the ability to easier track locals' activity on a federal level.

Comment: Hmm, could you elaborate a little more on what benefit comes from the communities being able to track this activity?

Comment: @TimStone The interests of people within a community have a greater chance of overlapping than the interest of people in any community. People want to participate in MSO posts of their interest and making them easier to find is good thing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to decide if this makes the most sense, or if really the communities should be bringing up these issues on their own metas first, and then escalating them to Meta (via migration or repost) after the fact.

Comment: @TimStone This post was prompted by a post on a child meta, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/is-there-a-way-to-find-posts-from-this-community-on-mso

Comment: Yeah, I saw that yesterday :)

Comment: @TimStone To be more clear of what I meant I have elaborated.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT:

OK, after reading your edits, and seeing that you're still hellbent on the fact that feature requests and bugs and the like should be migrated from child sites to meta.stackoverflow for the sole purpose of being aggregated, and that you want to have some utility on the child Stack Exchange site to monitor those that were migrated, aggregated, pooled or whatever, whether by user or by site, but I feel like you're missing something fundamental, or you're not being very persuasive.

A) Moderators have been informed to NOT migrate bugs, feature requests and support issues to MSO, because it does not benefit the overall community, primarily because of the solutions I highlighted below that were specifically put in place to help the team manage these things so that migrations weren't necessary (they were necessary before).

B) Just because a user wants to be active in another Stack Exchange site community does not require that his activities on another Stack Exchange site  be exposed intentfully to the community of another Stack Exchange site. I still stick by this is what you want from:

> So when a member of a community wants to deal with a question that needs to be dealt with globally rather than locally they make a post on MSO.
>
> Add a search or filter option that brings out posts where a certain community is active. Say that I use the filter option to filter out posts in which users from the Super User community is active. The filter would then show activity (questions, answers, comments, etc.) by MSO users who also has an active Super User account.

What I don't understand is how does this help you?

> Add a search or filter option that brings out posts where a certain community is active. Say that I use the filter option to filter out posts in which users from the Super User community is active. The filter would then show activity (questions, answers, comments, etc.) by MSO users who also has an active Super User account.

For exactly what purpose do you need to narrow down a user's posts on MSO that you can't by following their associated profile to Meta, click on Questions, and then order by date?

So far, everything you have asked for either already exists with a little effort (they have not yet worked up a query that cross mingles all your child meta posts with all the posts on MSO by users who have an active child meta post, because that's an unusual query that doesn't seem to serve any goals yet), or it already exists with no effort.

What the heck are you asking for man?

---

Here's the deal:

There are already ways on the network (see for instance: https://stackexchange.com/filters/13968/new-meta-posts) of finding the various bug and feature requests put onto any site on the network, and there are Stack Exchange employees that monitor those methods *right now* (they have been for over a year).

What this means to the user of an individual site is that they are no longer required to bring feature requests or bugs to [metaso] (this site) but can instead just post them on their own local meta (for instance, the meta at the site I moderate is http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com) and the child meta posts run into that query.

So while it might be neat to track the meta posts across all meta's by a single person, that sounds more like stalking. Instead, we need to encourage people to post their issues on their own local meta. That's the most direct place to fix them, as most issues are something that can be easily replicated on the site, or pertain only to the site (for instance, when *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/about)* (math.se) needed a way to display equations on the site, that was something that needed to be done only for math.se, or when my site had a theme issue the other day, that needed to be done on my site).

Now, if you're feeling brave and want to come over to this Meta and post feature requests or open a discussion, that's cool too, and nobody will be upset. But that "easy stalker" aspect is a bit ... creepy?

Comment: I followed that link and the first title I see starts with "Ban John".  :P

Comment: I really don't think that's an issue for [metase] ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand Thanks for you reply. I have updated my post with elaborations and I have included arguments against the criticism. About http://stackexchange.com/filters/13968/new-meta-posts . It is not the functionality I am suggesting. Also, it is rather hard to find since it floats around the other filter sets.